# perl escape character in function calls

Tags: perl

When I use a perl statement like,

`$workbook = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook->Parse(\($mechanize->content))`

where `$mechanize` is a `WWW::Mechanize` object, why do we escape the `$mechanize->content`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not escaping, it's referencing. Read more examples [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

> As a special case, \(@foo) returns a list of references to the
>   contents of @foo , not a reference to @foo itself. Likewise for %foo ,
>   except that the key references are to copies (since the keys are just
>   strings rather than full-fledged scalars).